# HTML form send to a php file for manipulation and come back to the same html page

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I want to know how can i send a `<FORM>` from a html pages to a PHP file (the PHP file will take data from the database) and it will come back to the same html pages?

----- >What i want is to eliminate the redirection.

As an example: GOOGLE

When you search website from google, you put your reference word in the textbar (searchbar) and the results will dynamically appears under.

Thanks for all

P.s: i know  how to do anything here except the dynamic appearence (and that's what i'm searching to do but i don't want to mixed up the HTML and the PHP in the file)

Comment: i found something ---> thanks JCOC611 
Also you made me realise why AJAX is so useful :D

Comment: I thought Google used Jquery which is ideally what you want ThorDozer to accomplish any dynamics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple example of what you need help with. Hope it helps.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp